# Mid-string RegEx/PHP whitespace removal works "elsewhere"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm new to **Regex in PHP**.  I suspect this will have a quick answer.

---

### **I have:**

`"Field A:       result xyz, Field  B:    result123,    Field   C: and this is another result        "`

---

### I need:

`"Field A:result xyz,Field B:result123,Field C:and this is another result "`

---

**...so basically I want to:**

> - *remove all **double** spaces*, and,
> - *remove all **single** spaces **if preceded** by `:` or `,`*

---

### My RegEx:

- Pattern: `([ :,])\s+`
- Replace: `${1}`

---

...works in **Notepad++**:

[image: img1]

---

...and *seems* like it *would* work on [**`regex101.com`**](https://regex101.com/r/89U4Zs/1) (if I knew how to actually replace on there):

[image: img2]

---

...***but* in PHP** with [`preg-replace`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php), different variations of the pattern I've tried are telling me:

`Unknown modifier '['` or `Unknown modifier '\'` or `Unknown modifier '+'`

---

...and I'm confident would work in **VBA** too. Here's the [cheatsheet](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/4/D240EBF6-A9BA-4E4F-A63F-AEB6DA0B921C/Regular%20expressions%20quick%20reference.pdf) I use but obviously it doesn't all apply to PHP...

Thoughts, please & thanks?

Comment: Can you post the exact PHP code you're trying to implement the RE with? (did you forget the delimiters?)

Comment: You must use the regex delimiters, `'/your_pattern/'`

Comment: You need to enclose the regex in delimiters like `/` i.e. `preg_replace('/([ :,])\s+/', '$1', $string);`

Comment: Ahhh... delimiters in PHP... got it, thanks all!